# Efficient assignment of a STL vector to another STL vector (WSL Issue)

Tags: c++, vector, clion, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have an issue regarding the time in which the assignment of STL vector is done.

**The context is:** I'm reading a binary file into a `std::vector` like this:

```
std::vector<float> read_file(const std::string &file_path) {

    std::ifstream stream(file_path);

    if (!stream.good()) {
        std::cout << "Cannot open file located at: " << file_path << std::endl;
        return std::vector<float>();
    }

    stream.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end);    
    auto size = stream.tellg();
    stream.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);

    std::vector<float> values(size / sizeof(float));
    stream.read((char*) &values[0], size);

    stream.close();

    return values;
}
```

I have **128 binary files** and each one contains **~2.500.000 float** values.

Eventually I will have **128** x `std::vector<float>` vectors. However I want them stored in a list/vector (matrix should say) which turns into this data structure: `std::vector<std::vector<float>>`.

**The problem is:**

**Example 1:** The execution time of this code snippet will take **~700ms**:

```
std::vector<float> data;
for (int i = 1; i <= 128; ++i) {
    data = read_file(getFile(i));
}
```

**Example 2:** But, the execution time of this code snippet will take **~2000ms**:

```
std::vector<std::vector<float>> data(128);
for (auto i = 1; i <= 128; ++i) {
    data[i-1] = read_file(getFile(i));
}
```

From my understanding, the assignment will perform a moving operation if the right side is a `vector&&` and a copying operation if the right side is `const vector&`. Taking into account the RVO it's worthless to add a `std::move` to the return type, hence the value returned will not be copied but moved. However the assignment in both examples should do the same thing: assign the address of the returned vector (the right side) to the vector on the left side.

**Question**: Based on my understanding (which may be wrong) and taking into account the both examples, why there is such a big difference in execution time between *Example1* and *Example2* if both perform the same operation (**the optimizations were activated**). Is there any improvement I can make to reduce the time of the second example? (I want to make the second example as efficient as possible)

Thanks.

Comment: Provide a wrapper class, that lets you view at a reference to your onedimensional vector and does the calculations to access rows and columns by integer indexes. Thus you won't need to copy anything at all.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Ok I kinda understand. (But wanted to show the true code since I really use this function for `int` values as well)

Comment: That's completely fine with me. However, when preparing your question for posting here, it's a good practice to strip unnecessary parts in order to avoid spurious effects of code you didn't even consider ([mcve]). BTW: If you're after improving the performance, consider a container that provides a read-only view and uses memory mapping in the background.

Comment: You might save some dynamic allocations if you do `std::vector<std::vector<float>> data; data.reserve(128);` and then push_back into the vector instead of `std::vector<std::vector<float>> data(128);`.

Comment: How did you test the execution time? The time difference could be caused by the os caching the files. This would result in a much lower time on the second run. I recommend using a profiler instead so you can see **which** part of the code actually slows down the operation.

Comment: It should be very obvious that your second example should be slower as it use much more memory.

Comment: @Phil1970 How is the different amount of memory a cause for an almost 3 fold slow down. In clang a `std::vector<float>` is 24 bytes. Creating 128 of them instead of just 1 increases your total memory consumption by approx. 3 KB. Since RVO applies in his samples, no unnecessary copies of the vector's **buffer** are made. Therefor, the 3 KB of those vector objects doesn't really matter since a single buffer is already 10 MB (2.5m floats). Yes, the memory footprint of both versions is different since the 2nd one doesn't free the memory. However the accumulated footprint is nearly identical.

Comment: 128 * 2.500.000 floats * 4 bytes per float = 1280 MB which is more than 1GB of extra memory. This is a lot if the computer has only 4GB of memory or so as the OS and other applications already take a good part of it.

Comment: @Timo I'm using `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` for measuring the execution time. I noticed that if I execute twice the example 1 (duplicating the lines)  even though the same code is executed, the second execution was faster with ~120ms - but this is another discussion subject. So, do you suggest that the computation of the execution time may be the bottleneck?

Comment: @Phil1970 yes it is over 1 GB in the end. But if the system memory gets that low that you have to use a swap file for the RAM, I'm pretty sure you get much worse performance than the 1300ms difference from op. If your memory is sufficent (say 8 GB) this causes no penalty whatsoever, as **both** samples allocate the same amount of memory, the first one just releases it partially over time.

Comment: @Shmwel I don't think that the time measurement is the bottleneck. I think measuring the time itself is a problem. Your code (at least as given here) reads some files and stores the content of them in some memory buffers. Since you aren't doing any expensive operations on the data after you read it, the verly large part of the computation will be done by reading the files themselfs. I assume that approx. 98% of your code's execution time goes to the `read_file` function (which you could determine exactly by using a profiler). Therefore, I assume that the os is the root cause of your results.

Comment: Of course, you could actually run into memory problems as you need around 1 GB of memory if you keep the vectors alive simultaniously. Did you verify that you have enough RAM available?

Comment: I have 10gigs or memory available. @Timo thanks for your suggestions though. I will try to run a profiler over it.

Comment: To have a better idea, you should do some timing without reading a file to get an idea of the time used by memory allocation alone. Also, you should also try to read the file without storing data into a vector (or reuse the same vector) so you have an idea of the time to read without memory allocation. **With those additional timing, you would have a much better idea of the actual impact of reading and allocation on the total performance**

Comment: @Phil1970 that's why I'm recommending a profiler the whole time... Don't do the measurement yourself, the profiler measures cpu ticks per operation. It can tell you exactly how much ressources (in this case cpu time) were used at which part of your code. That's what profilers are for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I identified is the WSL environment (through which I'm compiling, using CLion) that has a low I/O performance. Even though I didn't mention this aspect in my question, I had to compile the same program on various platforms and systems in order to understand what exactly is happening.

Setting up another building environment fixed the issue (the execution time is now very similar for Example 1 and 2 as well)

Answer (score 2):

**This is not an answer, it is a way to try to understand the difference of time, but this is too long to be given as a remark**

In the first case you always reuse the same blocks in memory, the needed size during the execution is small

But in the second solution you need 128 times more memory, may be that explain the difference of time ? and this is enforced if the execution time is the real time (swap during execution ?)

To compare the cases :

```
int main(int, char ** argv)
{
  switch (*argv[1]) {
  case '1':
    {
      // this is your first case
      std::vector<float> data;
      for (int i = 1; i <= 128; ++i) {
        data = read_file(getFile(i));
      }
    }
    break;
  case '2':
    {
      // this is your seconde case
      std::vector<std::vector<float>> data(128);
      for (auto i = 1; i <= 128; ++i) {
        data[i-1] = read_file(getFile(i));
      }
    }
    break;
  default:
    {
      // this is equivalent to your first case EXCEPT that needs 128 times more memory 
      std::vector<std::vector<float> *> data(128);
      for (auto i = 1; i <= 128; ++i) {
        data[i-1] = new std::vector<float>();
        *(data[i-1]) = read_file(getFile(i));
      }
    }
    break;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

When you run that with argument 3 do you get the time when the argument is 1 or 2 ? If 2 and 3 are similar that means the reason is the higher memory size needed.

Comment: The time between 2 and 3 is similar. However, it's quite interesting that the 128 vectors are already allocated (when the files are read) - shouldn't be just an address swap?

Comment: @Shmwel in the first solution this is not because you read 128 files that all of them stay in the heap. In the solution 2 and 3 all the read file contents stay in the heap, not in the first case where your have probably temporarily 2 files contents in the heap